# sublime 2_Find and replace only when target word and length match

Tags: regex

I am looking for a way to "find and replace(ctrl+shfit+f)" not only for the matching successive characters but length of the word.

For example code fragment like this

```
int a;
int b;
int c;

printf("I will be replaced as well cos I contain int!!");
```

where: int

replace with: float

will result in

```
float a;
float b;
float c;

prfloatf("I will be replaced as well cos I contain int!!");
```

To prevent from this happen I can think of adding length condition.  As long as solve my issue other than my idea will be welcomed :-)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\bint\b(?=(?:[^)(]*\([^)(]*\))*[^)(]*$)
```

Try this.This will replace the `int`'s you want.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/3

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regex to break on word boundaries - this implicitly gives you a length constraint.

The regex in this case would be

Find: `\bint\b`

Replace: `float`

Comment: Thank you for your step by step approach Evan!  I am new to regex so I did not know where to put "\bint\b" you mentioned.  It works very well! Happy!